# How to fix lagging issues in Lavalink?

Tags: java, discord.py, lavaplayer

I have a discord music bot built with discord.py and wavelink. I am using Soundcloud as music provider, but the song lags sometimes and I am not sure about the issue.

Configuration file of my Lavalink contains following two lines. Will changing these values help me?

```
bufferDurationMs: 500 # The duration of the NAS buffer. Higher values fare better against longer GC pauses
frameBufferDurationMs: 2000 # How many milliseconds of audio to keep buffered
```

The Lavalink server is hosted on a digital Ocean Ubantu droplet of 4GB RAM.

Java version: **13.0.7**

Any type of help or suggestion for further debugging will be very helpful.